# how don't self keyword saved and referenced as class name of last non-forwarding call in case the class itself has the invoked function?

Tags: php

While studying Late Static Binding in PHP , i read the below quotations:

> A “forwarding” call is a static call that is introduced by parent::, static:: or one called
>   by the function forward_static_call().
>   A call to self:: can also be a forwarding call if the class falls back to an inherited
>   class because it does not have the method defined
>
> Late static binding works by storing the class in the last “non-forwarding call”. In
>   other words, late static binding resolution will stop at a fully resolved static call.

According to the cited two points , look at the below example :

```
    class A {
 public static function foo() {
 echo static::who();
 }
 public static function who() {
 return 'A';
 }
}
class B extends A {
 public static function test() {
 self::foo();//this is non forward call because self will resolve to the current class because it has the function foo , so now the last stored class name of non forward call became B , then now the foo will be called and static must resolve to B not C.
 }

 public static function foo() {
 echo static::who();
 }

 public static function who() {
 return 'B';
 }


}
class C extends B {
     public static function who() {
 echo 'C';
 }
}
C::test(); //
```

At the point of self::foo() , self here is non-forwarding call because the class itself has the invoked function foo (which is the cited rule in above quotations) and according to the concept of Late Static Binding which stores class name of the last non-forwarding call, so now B is the last saved referenced class name, so now static in foo() must resolve to B, not C.

So, How do this wrong and static resolves to the initial non-forwarding call not the last?

Ref: PHP Zend Certification Study Guide.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The quote contains the answer:

> A call to self:: can also be a forwarding call if the class falls back to an inherited class because it does not have the method defined

In `test` you are calling `foo` which doesn't exist in class C, so the class falls back to inherited class B, and self:: will forward the calling information.

There is a similar exemple in the [page for Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php#example-240) (example #4) accompanied by a similar note:

> Late static bindings' resolution will stop at a fully resolved static call with no fallback. On the other hand, static calls using keywords like parent:: or self:: will forward the calling information.

Comment: at the step of self::foo(); , foo exists in the same function, so there is no forward because the function exists, so this is not forward call, and then self (B) will be saved as the last non-forward call , and as your cited example, the function there doesn't exist, so the forward will happened which is different case compared to the cited here.

Comment: @youhana No. At the step of `self::foo()` the calling class is C (add `echo get_called_class()`). `foo` doesn't in C. So `self` will forward the calling information, as written in the doc. The next call with `static` will go to C.